# how to stop interval for animation with its own speed in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out how to do this... I have a function that moves a div, this function has a speed property (500 ms), and its used for animate and move the div.. so, what I basically trying to do is everytime I am over a button call that function ,the problem is that I cant stop the interval after I leave the mouse (I am using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`) and I want to call that function delaying 500ms to call it (I tried with `myfunction().delay(500);` ) but its the same result...

Any idea how to do this? and how to stop my interval on mouseleave?

(for mouseleave I am using `clearInterval(myinterval);` ) but no result

```
jQuery('#next-div').mouseenter(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var interval = images.moving; //this function has an spped of animation of 400 each transaction
    }, 400); 
}).mouseleave(function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: You should show all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use classic JS:

```
function MyFunction() {
    setTimeout("[YOUR CODE HERE]", [DELAY IN MS])
}
```

That will delay whatever code passed to it from executing for the number of milliseconds specified in the second part of the function call. You can easily integrate that into whatever jQuery code you have already.